# How to convert 12 Hour format time to 24 Hour format in Excel

Tags: excel

How to change the Time from 05:14:40 PM to 17:14, I tried with changing format cell to 24 hours but couldn't get.

Comment: Can you post a snapshot of the value, with the formula bar, and the format you tried to use?

Comment: are you looking for [ format > custom > hh:mm:ss ] ?

Comment: =TEXT(A1,"hh:mm:ss AM/PM")    this is the formula which i'm using but not getting the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the cell and select Format cells option then click on Number menu tab option, select Time in Category column then select 13:30 in Type box.
now we can type/paste the time in that formatted cell for example 05:30:10 PM then that cell automatically shows the answer with 17:30.[image: Cell format option]